# bad font alignment using knitr and a non default font

Tags: r, fonts, knitr

I have some graphics that prints nicely directly typed as R code, but that generates a bad text alignment when generated by knitr.
Consider

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device="win")
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,section=c(rep("You",8),rep("Me",2))))+
geom_point(aes(x=x,y=x))+
ylab("my\nlabel")+
theme(text=element_text(family="Arial Unicode MS"))+facet_wrap(~section)
```

I get

[image: plot1]

Which is fine. then moving to knitr (with R markdown)

````
```{r dev=c('png')}
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device="win")
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,section=c(rep("You",8),rep("Me",2))))+
geom_point(aes(x=x,y=x))+
ylab("my\nlabel")+
theme(text=element_text(family="Arial Unicode MS"))+facet_wrap(~section)
```
````

I get some warnings (several times)

```
## Warning: unknown AFM entity encountered
## Warning: font width unknown for character 0x32
```

and the text becomes misaligned.

[image: plot2]

look at the y label.

I have exactly the same issue using the `cairo_pdf` device

the code becomes

```
library(ggplot2)
cairo_pdf("plot.pdf")
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,section=c(rep("You",8),rep("Me",2))))+
geom_point(aes(x=x,y=x))+
ylab("my\nlabel")+
theme(text=element_text(family="Arial Unicode MS"))+facet_wrap(~section)
dev.off()
```

for R
and

````
```{r dev=c('cairo_pdf')}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,section=c(rep("You",8),rep("Me",2))))+
geom_point(aes(x=x,y=x))+
ylab("my\nlabel")+
theme(text=element_text(family="Arial Unicode MS"))+facet_wrap(~section)
```
````

for knitr. The warning is now

```
## Warning: font family 'Arial Unicode MS' not found in PostScript font database
```

but the image show the same issue as before.

I have reproduced this issue on both a win7 and a MacOS X platform with R 3.0.1

I guess there might be a simple solution to solve this issue, but I did not manage to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I have observed similar behaviour with panel and plot margins being messed up in knitr output but working fine when printing to png directly. It would seem that knitr applies a different theme somehow, overwriting the specified properties?!

Comment: I have finally used a workaround with a homemade function that calls directly the cairo_pdf engine and adds all the code necessary in the Markdown file. I could not found a solution within knitr.

Comment: @user2147028 I realize this is an old post, so hopefully you are still active on this site. I am having the issue described. It would be really helpful for others with the same problem if you could post your workaround homemade function. Perhaps put it in an answer to your own question. You can even mark your solution as the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the root cause, but you might be able to fix it by adjusting the `vjust` argument in the `axis.title.y` element of the theme.  Something like

```
theme(
  text=element_text(family="Arial Unicode MS"),
  axis.title.y=element_text(family="Arial Unicode MS", vjust = 0)
)
```

Comment: This does not do the trick. The label is now misaligned toward the edge of the graph. Moreover I tried to give a minimal example here, my actual graph are more complex and the misalignment cause issues in all the labels (x,y,strips,legend). Thanks you for your answer anyway